# Scan for BLE device and connected to them

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello I'm a beginner and I kind of need help with something, I need my app  to scan for BLE device and return it in a `listView`, the problem is I can't find a way to do it

```
private fun listedevice() {

    val BLEdevice = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Liste of available device")

    val inflater = layoutInflater
    val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ble_connection, null)

    val listviewDevice = dialogLayout.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.deviceListView)

    // Exemple de données
    val deviceList = listOf("Device 1", "Device 2", "Device 3")

    // Créer un adaptateur de liste et l'associer à la ListView
    val adapter =
        ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList)
        listviewDevice.adapter = adapter

    BLEdevice.setView(dialogLayout)

    BLEdevice.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
     // Vous pouvez accéder aux éléments sélectionnés ici si nécessaire
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    BLEdevice.setNegativeButton("Annuler") { dialog, which ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    val dialog = BLEdevice.create()
    dialog.show()
```

here is the part of my code, I need to have the value `devicelist` filled with the device that is scanned

I try to scan for BLE devices and be able to connect to them to send them information

Comment: Do you have problems searching for BLE devices or with displaying the results?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan i have probleme with scanning and then dispaying it

Comment: Did you follow the [official Android guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/find-ble-devices#kotlin) or any other guide to get this working? Do you have any specific problems?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan yes i followed it but i encounter a lot of unsolved reference for thing that i cant import
i'm working on a different guide rn thats seems to work but if you have explanation i'm ok for it

Comment: Maybe take a look at [ask] to refine your question then. Without a specific problem you encounter right now it is hard to help you